# applying sapply or other apply function instead of nested for loop for lists of data frames

Tags: r, list, for-loop, apply, sapply

I have two data frames/ lists of datas 'humanSplit`and`ratSplit` and they are of the form

```
> ratSplit$Kidney_F_GSM1328570
  ratGene        ratReplicate alignment RNAtype
1    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570         7     REV
2    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570        12     REV
3    Crot Kidney_F_GSM1328570         4     REV
```

and

```
> humanSplit$Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt
   humanGene                            humanReplicate alignment RNAtype
53     ZFP28 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         5     reg
55     RC3H1 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         9     reg
56     IFI27 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L009_R1_report.txt         4     reg
```

And another file used below is geneList of the form:

```
ABAT,Abat
ABCA1,Abca1
ABCA12,Abca12
ABCA2,Abca2
ABCA3,Abca17
ABCA4,Abca4
ABCA5,Abca5
```

now I want to do fisher's exact test between all the elements pair combination between `ratSplit` and `humanSplit` after some data manipulation. And ultimately want to write the result of fisher's test in a `csv` file. Right now I am doing double for loop. But I am wondering how I can use `sapply` or other related things to make it more efficient.

currently I am doing the following thing: Here I am first making a `data.frame` `result` where I store/append all the information got from fisher's test in a pair in each step. Then finally when the whole loop is done, I write the final `result` in a `csv` file. my understanding is to use `sapply` I need to transform the inside of the loop into a function and then call sapply. But I am not sure what's the best way to optimize it. Any help would be much appreciated

```
result <- data.frame(humanReplicate = "human_replicate", ratReplicate = "rat_replicate", pvalue = "p-value", alternative = "alternative_hypothesis", 
                     Conf.int1 = "conf.int1", Conf.int2 ="conf.int2", oddratio = "Odd_Ratio")
for(i in 1:length(ratSplit)) {
  for(j in 1:length(humanSplit)) {
    ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[i])
    humanReplicateName <- names(humanSplit[j])

    #merging above two based on the one-to-one gene mapping as in geneList defined above.
    mergedHumanData <-merge(geneList,humanSplit[[j]], by.x = "human", by.y = "humanGene")
    mergedRatData <- merge(geneList, ratSplit[[i]], by.x = "rat", by.y = "ratGene")

    mergedHumanData <- mergedHumanData[,c(1,2,4,5)] #rearrange column
    mergedRatData <- mergedRatData[,c(2,1,4,5)]  #rearrange column
    mergedHumanRatData <- rbind(mergedHumanData,mergedRatData) #now the columns are "human", "rat", "alignment", "RNAtype"

    agg <- aggregate(RNAtype ~ human+rat, data= mergedHumanRatData, FUN=getGeneType) #agg to make HmYn form
    HmRnTable <- table(agg$RNAtype) #table of HmRn ie RNAtype in human and rat.

    #now assign these numbers to variables HmYn. Consider cases when some form of HmRy is not present in the table. That's why
    #is.integer0 function is used
    HyRy <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRy"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRy"][[1]])
    HnRn <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRn"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRn"][[1]])
    HyRn <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRn"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HyRn"][[1]])
    HnRy <- ifelse(is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRy"]), 0, HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == "HnRy"][[1]])

    contingencyTable <- matrix(c(HnRn,HnRy,HyRn,HyRy), nrow = 2)

    fisherTest <- fisher.test(contingencyTable) 
    newLine <- data.frame(t(c(humanReplicate = humanReplicateName, ratReplicate = ratReplicateName, pvalue = fisherTest$p,
                              alternative = fisherTest$alternative, Conf.int1 = fisherTest$conf.int[1], Conf.int2 =fisherTest$conf.int[2], 
                              oddratio = fisherTest$estimate[[1]])))


    result <-rbind(result,newLine)
  }
}

write.table(result, file = "newData5.csv", row.names = FALSE, append = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, sep = ",")
```

Comment: have a look at `outer`. It looks like you could use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to test this since we're missing `geneList`, but I'm inferring that the code works correctly, so you merely want to speed things up. Here are some pointers to help:

1. Don't predefine `result` like this. By setting the first entry of each column to be a string *of the column name*, you ensure that all subsequent entries will be coerced into strings. Though this doesn't necessarily bite you since you're eventually writing to a CSV anyway, it's bad form. It will bite you if you intend to read it back in to R, since the first row will be used as the column names, but the second row will all be strings forcing subsequent data to be strings as well. (You'll then have to clean your own data, wasteful.)
2. At the end of your script, you call `rbind`. This might do alright for a while, but repeated calls to `rbind` will result in the whole data.frame being copied each time. With more rows being appended, this will cause a not-insignificant slowdown in your code. This can be fixed by one of two methods, listed below.
3. Since you use each of `names(HmRnTable) == "HyRy"` twice, my technique is to first save that to a vector (or scalar if you use `which(...)`), and then use this variable in the subsetting of `HmRnTable`. It will likely speed things up *a little* but may also make the code a little easier to read. In fact, you can shorten each of those four assignments to something like (untested):

   ```
   idx <- is.integer0(HmRnTable[names(HmRnTable) == 'HyRy'])
   HyRy <- HmRnTable[idx][[1]]
   HyRy[idx] <- 0
   ## repeat for HyRn, HnRy, and HnRn
   ```
4. I strongly urge you to take the majority of the code and put it in a function that takes either two arguments (`i` and `j`) or four arguments (list1, index1, list2, index2). (Which you do depends on how much OCD you have with regards to variable scope references.) I'll assume that the function will literally return the results from `fisher.test` with no massaging. This will make for much easier testing while making the function, and for inclusion later on in this script. I'll reference function as `myfisher(i,j)` below.
5. I'm inferring that you have a high number of comparisons to run (since each iteration really shouldn't take that long). @Floo0's comment about `outer` can work, as can `expand.grid`. Either way, you are comparing each element of list1 with each element of list2. If you start with:

   ```
   (eg <- expand.grid(i = 1:length(ratSplit),
                      j = 1:length(humanSplit)))
   ##    i j
   ## 1  1 1
   ## 2  2 1
   ## 3  3 1
   ## 4  4 1
   ## ...
   ```

   This gives us an easy data.frame on which we can use `apply`. Honestly, though, I like the elegance of `ddply` in this case, since it easily goes *from* a data.frame *to* a data.frame, easily.

   ```
   library(plyr)
   ret <- ddply(eg, .(i, j), function(df) {
       with(myfisher(df$i, df$j),
            data.frame(pv = p.value, ci1 = conf.int[1], ci2 = conf.int[2],
                       alt = alternative))
   })
   ```

   Note that I expressly did not include `humanReplicateName` or `ratReplicateName` since those can be added before the ddply (or after, referencing `ret$` instead of `eg$`) with:

   ```
   eg$ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[ eg$i ])
   eg$humanReplicateName <- names(humanSplit[ eg$i ])
   ```

   and the names will magically be in the output, too. Less to deal with inside the loop.

   Up until now, this will result in one data.frame that you can then save to a CSV.

   I'll make one more recommendation that may be overkill depending on how long this will be running. I've found at times that my long-running scripts are interrupted, perhaps because I had to adjust something on-the-fly; I found a bug; or if the computer had to reboot. There is no easy way to allow mid-stream continuation, but I've worked some techniques to mitigate that.
6. Instead of `ddply`, use `d_ply` which does not assume the type of the return value. Instead of returning a (single-row) data.frame, immediately save that one row (with or without headers, your call) to a file. Though the below code is not truly "atomic" and therefore race-conditions *may* occur, it's robust enough to meet most of our needs:

   ```
   library(plyr)
   savedir <- './output'
   ret <- ddply(eg, .(i, j), function(df) {
       fn <- file.path(savedir, sprintf('%s-%s.csv', df$i, df$j))
       if (! file.exists(fn)) {
           ret <- with(myfisher(df$i, df$j),
                       data.frame(pv = p.value, ci1 = conf.int[1], ci2 = conf.int[2],
                                  alt = alternative))
           write.table(ret, file = fn, sep = ",", append = FALSE, 
                       row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
       }
   })
   ```

   One goodness of this is that if/when it is interrupted, the *most* you will have to do is look at all of the files within "./output/", delete files with 0 bytes, and then re-run and it will only execute on the missing files. Oh, and it gets better.
7. Parallelizing it. If you need to go this far (and some functions don't see as much improvement as others), you can instead use multiple cores on your system. You could do something like this:

   ```
   library(parallel)
   cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1) # I like to keep one free
   clusterEvalQ(cl, {
       load('myTwoLists.rda') # with ratSplit and humanSplit variables
       source('mycode.R') # with myfisher(i,j)
       ## any libraries you may want/need to add, if you get more advanced
   })
   eg <- expand.grid(i = 1:length(ratSplit),
                     j = 1:length(humanSplit))
   eg$ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[ eg$i ])
   eg$humanReplicateName <- names(humanSplit[ eg$i ])
   ign <- parApply(cl, eg, 1, function(r) {
       i <- r[1] ; j <- r[2]
       fn <- file.path(savedir, sprintf('%s-%s.csv', i, j)
       if (! file.exists(fn)) {
           ret <- with(myfisher(i, j),
                       data.frame(ratName = r[3], humanName = r[4],
                                  pv = p.value, ci1 = conf.int[1], ci2 = conf.int[2],
                                  alt = alternative))
           write.table(ret, file = fn, sep = ",", append = FALSE, 
                       row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE)
       }
   })
   stopCluster(cl)
   ```

   Notice that we aren't referencing the row as a data.frame anymore. I'd love it if Hadley's code worked natively with parallel. <s>(For all I know, it does and I just haven't found it yet!)</s> **Edit:** none of my past projects using `parallel` were using `ddply`, and vice versa, so I have never played with `ddply(..., .parallel = TRUE)` which uses `foreach`.

***Caveat Emptor***: this code has not been tested in this context, though it is almost copy/pasted from working code. Because of edits, I may be off-by-one or missing a paren. Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks a lot! I added few lines of geneList.txt  now! Thanks for the long explanation. I am trying this now.

Comment: FYI: this type of question (one that works but you want to improve the code) can also be asked at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), a part of SO.

Comment: library(plyr)
    ret <- ddply(eg, .(i, j), function(df) {
        with(myfisher(df$i, df$j),
             data.frame(pv = p.value, ci1 = conf.int[1], ci2 =    conf.int[2],
                        alt = alternative))
    })

I am wondering in this part, where the code is getting data from ratSplit and humanSplit. Could you explain a bit more? it's showing error

Comment: The `myfisher` is a function that you write that does all of the preprocessing, creates the contingency table, and runs `fisher.test`. You can "violate function scope" by having `myfisher` just reach out and use the data from the `.GlobalEnv`, or you can pass the lists to `ddply` and subsequently to `myfisher`, with something like this: `ddply(eg, .(i,j), function(df, list1, list2) with(myfisher(df$i, list1, df$j, list2), data.frame(...)), ratSplit, humanSplit)`. I personally prefer the latter but some find it overly complicated, so I often show it the simpler way first.

Comment: Of course, encompassing most of your code into a function is completely optional. I find it helpful, especially in this situation, because it allows you to do incremental testing. For instance, test manually on known pairs. Then create `eg` and run `myfisher(eg[1,1], ratSplit, eg[1,2], humanSplit)`. Then run `with(myfisher(eg[1,1], ratSplit, eg[1,2], humanSplit), data.frame(pv=p.value, ...))`, and finally test within `ddply` on several rows. When I'm using new (to me) structures/functions, I tend to test like that before running it on all n-thousand combinations.

Comment: If this works for an answer, please accept it (you've accepted answers before). If not, can you say what isn't working for you?