# R: passing by parameter to function and using apply instead of nested loop and recursive indexing failed

Tags: r, function, nested-loops, apply

I have two lists of lists. `humanSplit` and `ratSplit`. `humanSplit` has element of the form::

```
> humanSplit[1]
$Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L001_R1_report.txt
   humanGene                            humanReplicate alignment RNAtype
66      DGKI Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L001_R1_report.txt         6     reg
68   ARFGEF2 Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L001_R1_report.txt         5     reg
```

If you type  `humanSplit[[1]]`, it gives the data without name `$Fetal_Brain_408_AGTCAA_L001_R1_report.txt`

`RatSplit` is also essentially similar to `humanSplit` with difference in column order. I want to apply `fisher's test` to every possible pairing of replicates from `humanSplit` and `ratSplit`. Now I defined the following empty vector which I will use to store the informations of my fisher's test

```
humanReplicate <- vector(mode = 'character', length = 0)
ratReplicate <- vector(mode = 'character', length = 0)
pvalue  <- vector(mode = 'numeric', length = 0)
```

For fisher's test between two replicates of humanSplit and ratSplit, I define the following function. In the function I use `geneList' which is a data.frame made by reading a file and has form:

```
> head(geneList)
    human     rat
1 5S_rRNA 5S_rRNA
2 5S_rRNA 5S_rRNA
```

Now here is the main function, where I use a function `getGenetype` which I already defined in other part of the code. Also `x` and `y` are integers :

```
fishertest <-function(x,y) {
  ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[x])
  humanReplicateName <- names(humanSplit[y])

  ## merging above two based on the one-to-one gene mapping as in geneList
  ## defined above.
  mergedHumanData <-merge(geneList,humanSplit[[y]], by.x = "human", by.y = "humanGene")
  mergedRatData <- merge(geneList, ratSplit[[x]], by.x = "rat", by.y = "ratGene")

  ## [here i do other manipulation with using already defined function
  ## getGenetype that is defined outside of this function and make things
  ## necessary to define following contingency table]

  contingencyTable <- matrix(c(HnRn,HnRy,HyRn,HyRy), nrow = 2)
  fisherTest <- fisher.test(contingencyTable)
  humanReplicate <- c(humanReplicate,humanReplicateName )
  ratReplicate <- c(ratReplicate,ratReplicateName )
  pvalue <- c(pvalue , fisherTest$p)

}
```

After doing all this I do the make matrix `eg` to use in `apply`. Here I am basically trying to do something similar to double for loop and then using `fisher`

```
eg <- expand.grid(i = 1:length(ratSplit),j = 1:length(humanSplit))
junk = apply(eg, 1, fishertest(eg$i,eg$j))
```

Now the problem is, when I try to run, it gives the following error when it tries to use function `fishertest` in `apply`

```
Error in humanSplit[[y]] : recursive indexing failed at level 3
```

Rstudio points out problem in following line:

```
mergedHumanData <-merge(geneList,humanSplit[[y]], by.x = "human", by.y = "humanGene")
```

Ultimately, I want to do the following:

```
result <- data.frame(humanReplicate,ratReplicate, pvalue ,alternative, Conf.int1, Conf.int2, oddratio)
```

I am struggling with these questions:

In defining `fishertest` function, how should I pass `ratSplit` and `humanSplit` and already defined function `getGenetype`?

And how I should use `apply` here?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put a `browser` in front of the offending line and inspect the element. Without the data and full code, it's hard to call what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up front: read `?apply`. Additionally, the first three hits on google when searching for "R apply tutorial" are helpful snippets: [one](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-r-apply-function-a-tutorial-with-examples/), [two](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-apply-sapply-lapply-in-r/), and [three](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/).

### Errors in `fishertest()`

The error message itself has nothing to do with `apply`. The reason it got as far as it did is because the arguments you provided actually resolved. Try to do `eg$i` by itself, and you'll see that it is returning a vector: the corresponding column in the `eg` data.frame. You are passing this vector as an index in the `i` argument. The primary reason your function erred out is because double-bracket indexing (`[[`) only works with singles, not vectors of length greater than 1. This is a great example of where production/deployed functions would need type-checking to ensure that each argument is a numeric of length 1; often not required for quick code but would have caught this mistake. Had it not been for the `[[` limit, your function may have returned incorrect results. (I've been bitten by that many times!)

BTW: your code is also incorrect in its scoped access to `pvalue`, et al. If you make your function return *just* the numbers you need and the aggregate it *outside* of the function, your life will simplify. (`pvalue <- c(pvalue, ...)` will find `pvalue` assigned outside the function but will not update it as you want. You are defeating one purpose of writing this into a function. When thinking about writing this function, try to answer *only* this question: *"how do I compare a single rat record with a single human record?"* Only after that works correctly and simply without having to overwrite variables in the parent environment should you try to answer the question *"how do I apply this function to all pairs and aggregate it?"* Try very hard to have your function *not* change anything outside of its own environment.

### Errors in `apply()`

Had your function worked properly despite these errors, you would have received the following error from `apply`:

```
apply(eg, 1, fishertest(eg$i, eg$j))
## Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
##  'fishertest(eg$i, eg$j)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

When you call `apply` in this sense, it it parsing the third argument and, in this example, evaluates it. Since it is simply a call to `fishertest(eg$i, eg$j)` which is intended to return a data.frame row (inferred from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223808/applying-sapply-or-other-apply-function-instead-of-nested-for-loop-for-lists-of/)), it resolves to such, and `apply` then sees something akin to:

```
apply(eg, 1, data.frame(...))
```

Now that you see that `apply` is being handed a data.frame and not a function.

The third argument (FUN) needs to be a function itself that takes as its first argument a vector containing the elements of the row (1) or column (2) of the matrix/data.frame. As an example, consider the following contrived example:

```
eg <- data.frame(aa = 1:5, bb = 11:15)
apply(eg, 1, mean)
## [1]  6  7  8  9 10
# similar to your use, will not work; this error comes from mean not getting
# any arguments, your error above is because
apply(eg, 1, mean())
## Error in mean.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Realize that `mean` is a function itself, not the return value from a function (there is more to it, but this definition works). Because we're iterating over the rows of `eg` (because of the 1), the first iteration takes the first row and calls `mean(c(1, 11))`, which returns 6. The equivalent of your code here is `mean()(c(1, 11))` will fail for a couple of reasons: (1) because `mean` requires an argument and is not getting, and (2) regardless, it does not return a function itself (in a "functional programming" paradigm, easy in R but uncommon for most programmers).

In the example here, `mean` will accept a single argument which is typically a vector of numerics. In your case, your function `fishertest` requires two arguments (templated by my [previous answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223808/applying-sapply-or-other-apply-function-instead-of-nested-for-loop-for-lists-of/25225175#25225175)), which does not work. You have two options here:

1. Change your `fishertest` function to accept a single vector as an argument and parse the index numbers from it. Bothing of the following options do this:

   ```
   fishertest <- function(v) {
     x <- v[1]
     y <- v[2]
     ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[x])
     ## ...
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   fishertest <- function(x, y) {
     if (missing(y)) {
       y <- x[2]
       x <- x[1]
     }
     ratReplicateName <- names(ratSplit[x])
     ## ...
   }
   ```

   The second version allows you to continue using the manual form of `fishertest(1, 57)` while also allowing you to do `apply(eg, 1, fishertest)` verbatim. Very readable, IMHO. (Better error checking and reporting can be used here, I'm just providing a MWE.)
2. Write an anonymous function to take the vector and split it up appropriately. This anonymous function could look something like `function(ii) fishertest(ii[1], ii[2])`. This is typically how it is done for functions that either do not transform as easily as in #1 above, or for functions you cannot or do not want to modify. You can either assign this intermediary function to a variable (which makes it no longer anonymous, figure that) and pass that intermediary to `apply`, or just pass it directly to `apply`, ala:

   ```
   .func <- function(ii) fishertest(ii[1], ii[2])
   apply(eg, 1, .func)
   ## equivalently
   apply(eg, 1, function(ii) fishertest(ii[1], ii[2]))
   ```

   There are two reasons why many people opt to name the function: (1) if the function is used multiple times, better to define once and reuse; (2) it makes the `apply` line easier to read than if it contained a complex multi-line function definition.

As a side note, there are some gotchas with using `apply` and family that, if you don't understand, will be confusing. Not the least of which is that when your function returns vectors, the matrix returned from `apply` will need to be transposed (with `t()`), after which you'll still need to `rbind` or otherwise aggregrate.

This is one area where using `ddply` may provide a more readable solution. There are several tutorials showing it off. For a quick intro, read [this](http://plyr.had.co.nz/09-user/); for a more in depth discussion on the bigger picture in which `ddply` plays a part, read Hadley's [Split, Apply, Combine Strategy for Data Analysis](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01) paper from JSS.